# Wildfly 17.0.0.1.Final 's console on AWS doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, jboss, wildfly

I installed Wildfly 17.0.0.1.Final on Linux CentOS on AWS, and I can successfully land on the welcome page of Wildfly, but when I try to enter the Admin console, it just fails to load the page(timeout).
Any idea on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Edit management bind address in JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml. Change management address to 0.0.0.0 (Default is 127.0.0.1)

```
<interface name="management">
      <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
</interface>
```

Or start wildfly with below command

```
$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0
```